# Query that saves data in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing an SP in SQL SERVER, and I need one of the steps to execute a query that comes with data from another variable and save that result in another variable for later use in SP. The code I am using displays the following error:

Procedure expects parameter '@handle' of type 'int'.

```
DECLARE @retorno INT, @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @parametro NVARCHAR(4000), @caminho NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @caminho = '\\arquivos\CÉLULA DE INOVAÇÃO\SQL\19072019.CSV'
SET @parametro = N'@retornoOut INT OUTPUT'
SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(RIGHT('''+@caminho+''',12),1,8)'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_execute @sql, @parametro, @retornoOut=@retorno OUTPUT;
```

The purpose of the code is from a file passed by the user, I can get the name from the given path. I don't know what could be wrong with id.

Comment: You are passing the literal string `N'@retornoOut INT OUTPUT'` as the value of @parametro

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that youre using sp_execute , when you should use **sp_executesql**

this works fine

```
DECLARE @retorno INT, @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @parametro NVARCHAR(4000), @caminho NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @caminho = '\\arquivos\CÉLULA DE INOVAÇÃO\SQL\19072019.CSV'
SET @parametro = N'@retornoOut INT OUTPUT'
SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(RIGHT('''+@caminho+''',12),1,8)'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @parametro, @retornoOut=@retorno OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use dynamic SQL for this. You can just use `set` or a simple `select`:

Using set:

```
SET @retorno =  SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@caminho,12),1,8)
```

Using select:

```
SELECT @retorno =  SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@caminho,12),1,8)
```